# Что не так с консльной командой?

Tags: yii2

в папке `console/controller`
создал

```
<?php
namespace console\controllers;
use yii\console\Controller;
class earningsController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        return "yes"
    }
}
```

пытаюсь вызвать `php yii earnings/create`
получаю `Unknown command: earnings/create`
делаю так

```
...
- earnings                     
- fixture  ...
```

подскажите что делаю не так ?

Comment: Возможно проблема в том что название контроллера с маленькой буквы - earningsController? Оно должно совпадать с названием файла.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan точно туплю пишите ответ подтвержу спасибо.

Comment: Бывает, обычно IDE такое подсказывать должна

Comment: @Sergalas какой смысл писать ответы на вопрос, который вызван опечаткой? Такие должны просто закрываться по соответствующей причине

Comment: @АлексейШиманский почему опечаткой ни где в документации не описано что консольные контроллеры должны быть с большой буквы это не очевидно.

Comment: @Sergalas а что такое PSR и в принципе codeStyle вам не ведомы? Это база самого языка программирования и стандарты

Comment: @Sergalas ну и да: [Yii 2 Core Framework Code Style](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/internals/core-code-style.md) ..... конкретный пункт 3 и 4 -
 https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/internals/core-code-style.md#3-class-names

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я там кое что поправил посмотрите. Так уже не опечатка ?

Comment: @Sergalas не надо менять вопрос, если есть другой - надо задавать новый

Comment: @АлексейШиманский подождите ошибка не ушла и не решена. Почему я меняю вопрос хорошо в начале была опечатка но ошибка не решена же

Comment: @Sergalas там очередная опечатка. в которой наверняка затесалась русская буква.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский специально полностью переименовал на английской клавиатуре эффект тот же

Comment: @Sergalas чудес не бывает. попробуй с нуля создать базовый HelloCobtroller https://latcoding.com/2015/08/27/run-controller-yii2-via-console/  копируя код.. и посмотри будет ли работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том что у вас название контроллера не совпадает с названием файла, напишите его с большой буквы:

```
class EarningsController extends Controller
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь возникла ещё ошибка

Comment: @Sergalas задайте другой вопрос